react native borderRadius зазубренные края
Пишу приложение на React Native для AndroidTV, столкнулся с такой проблемой, при указании элементам скругление краев borderRadius, края почему-то зазубренные а не просто круглые.
Изображение
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим, может есть какое-то решение?

Добрый вечер, абсолютно та же проблема на андроид, подскажите пожалуйста, какое-то решение проблемы Вам удалось найти?
